# Format part of string using formula

Tags: excel

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without using vba. At the moment I have a column full of ID numbers for a Test Script that I am constructing.

The ID's up until now have been `001; 002; 003;....etc` Now what I'm trying to do is auto populate the ID but prepending `CLL-` to the front of the ID to give me `CLL-001`

I'm using the formula

```
="CLL-" & ROW()-1
```

However, this returns `CLL-1`. What I'd like to do is have the numerical part of the ID formatted to 3 s.f. but I can't see a way to do this without using vba. Therefore is there anyway to do this in an excel formula instead of using something like:

```
cell.value = "CLL-" & Format(cell.row-1, "000")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`="CLL-" & TEXT(ROW()-1,"000")` is one way.

This will break down on row 1001. You could use a `MOD` to maintain only 3 digits.

Comment: This seems to work fine on row `1048576` I plan to strip out the formulas and just paste the values once I've finished writing the document so all ID references will remain constant. This is just to generate them whilst writing. Is there any alternative to ROW. I'm populating a table (listobject) so it would be quite handy if I could return the row of that (like in vba) instead of the sheet

Comment: The ROW() function is not volatile. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730921%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: An idiomatic way is to write 1 at the top of a column (say column B), then in cell B2, write = B1 + 1 and copy downwards.

Comment: @teylyn: didn't believe you at first but have tested it. Thank you.

Comment: A great article about volatile functions and a test file to test if functions are volatile can be seen at Charles Williams' site [here](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm)